# Using Comparator to sort an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

i ran into a bit of a problem. Im using an ArrayList to create a Football league table. Now what i need to do is sort the ArrayList using the ClubPoints.I tried using a comparator, but not really sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated

```
  ArrayList<FootballClub> newClub = new ArrayList<FootballClub>(); 

String format = "|%1$-15s|%2$-15s|%3$-15s|%4$-15s|%5$-15s|%6$-15s|%7$-15s|%8$-15s|%9$-15s|\n";
                    System.out.format(format, "Score", "Name", "Location", "Wins", "Losses", "Draws", 
                            "Goals Received", "Goals Scored", "Games Played");
                    for(int x = 0; x < newClub.size(); x++){

                    Collections.sort(newClub, new DescendingByPointsComparator());  

                    System.out.format(format, newClub.get(x).ClubScore, newClub.get(x).ClubName, newClub.get(x).ClubLocation, 
                            newClub.get(x).ClubWins, newClub.get(x).ClubLosses, newClub.get(x).ClubDraws, newClub.get(x).GoalsReceived, 
                            newClub.get(x).GoalsScored, newClub.get(x).ClubGamesPlayed);

                    }


class DescendingByPointsComparator implements Comparator<FootballClub> {
    @Override
    public int compare(FootballClub lhs, FootballClub rhs) {
        return Integer.compare(rhs.getPoints(), lhs.getPoints());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have now?

Comment: I get an error in the class DescendingByPointsComparator  "Cannot Find Symbol: method getPoints()"

Comment: Then the definition of `FootballClub` would seem to be pertinent, no?

Comment: Note that there's no point to sort **in** the for loop, that's odd you probably want to sort outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

In your `FootballClub` model class, you can override the following method to achieve what you want:

```
public int compareTo(FootballClub anotherFootballClub){

    // Your comparison logic here
    return //negative integer if this instance is lesser and vice versa
}
```

Also, make sure your `FootballClub` class implements `Comparable`

Comment: if "FootballClub class implements Comparable" there's no need to specify a Comparator..